# In App Purchase Error in Static codes

Tags: android, android-intent, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I am using current code for purchase for calling purchase intent

```
Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, pContext.getPackageName(), "android.test.canceled", "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXv");
Set<String> allKeys = buyIntentBundle.keySet();
Object  responseCode= buyIntentBundle.get("RESPONSE_CODE");
Object  intent= buyIntentBundle.get("BUY_INTENT");
Log.i(TAG,"buyIntentBundle"+buyIntentBundle.keySet()+"responseCode"+responseCode+"intent"+intent);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
if (pendingIntent != null) {
    pContext.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 2013, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),Integer.valueOf(0));
}
```

Now onActivityResult i am checking

```
if (requestCode == 2013) {           
    Log.i(TAG, "onactivity result called inside request code");
    int responseCode = intent.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
    String purchaseData = intent.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
    String dataSignature = intent.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");      
    if (responseCode == Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
        String sku = jo.getString("productId");
        Toast.makeText(pContext, "You have bought the " + sku + ". Excellent choice, adventurer!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        JSONObject o = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
        String mOrderId = o.optString("orderId");
        String mPackageName = o.optString("packageName");
        String mSku = o.optString("productId");
        long mPurchaseTime = o.optLong("purchaseTime");
        int mPurchaseState = o.optInt("purchaseState");
        String mDeveloperPayload = o.optString("developerPayload");
        String mToken = o.optString("token", o.optString("purchaseToken"));
        try {
            mService.consumePurchase(3, pContext.getPackageName(), mToken);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }//consumePurchase
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(pContext, "Failed to parse purchase data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }else if (responseCode == Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED) {
         Toast.makeText(pContext, "User cancelled purchase.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }else if (responseCode == Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE) {
         Toast.makeText(pContext, "Your Device doesn't support inapp billing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }else if (responseCode == Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE) {
         Toast.makeText(pContext, "Item is not available for billing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }else if (responseCode == Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR) {
         Toast.makeText(pContext, "Can't purchase item due to some developer error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }else if (responseCode == Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ERROR) {
         Toast.makeText(pContext, "Can't purchase item due to some error in response.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }else if (responseCode == Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
         Toast.makeText(pContext, "You already own this item.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }else if (responseCode == Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_NOT_OWNED) {
         Toast.makeText(pContext, "You don't own this item.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

Since i am calling "android.test.canceled" so i should be getting BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED this response but it shows as payment successful and returns responseCode as BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK with no other parameter in that intent.getExtras.
I am trying static responses 
   http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static

Thanks & Regards!!

Comment: I was confused by the same behavior and I think the actual Android developers should modify the code. If you (or anyone else) still need to test user_cancelled response, just press backspace. The response code will be BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USED_CANCELED.

Answer (score 3):

You are not checking:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    ....
}
```

It's possible that the process does not complete successfully. And since the default value for `responseCode` in case that key "RESPONSE_CODE" is not present in `intent` is "0"....

```
int responseCode = intent.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
```

.... `responseCode` is initialized to `Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK` == > `0`.

Try using:

```
int responseCode = intent.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", -1);
```

And add a final `else` block to handle `-1`.

Comment: The resultCode equals RESULT_OK when using android.test.canceled

Comment: @MrThys Ok. Did you try using `int responseCode = intent.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", -1);`. Does `responseCode` still initialize to `0`?

Comment: Jep, I have set the default to -1 and it still returns 0